# Open page with a pre expanded table row

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap table with expandable rows, what I want is, opening the page with an already expanded row (say first row).

Below is the table I am using.

```
    <table class="table no-padding-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Date2</th>
              <th>Date3</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
            <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#extend{{$index}}"
                                    ng-repeat-start="date in dates">
                <td>
                    <p>{{date}}</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>{{date}}</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>{{date}}</p>
                </td>
             </tr>
             <tr ng-repeat-end="">
                 <td colspan="3" class="hiddenRow">
                    <div class="accordian-body collapse">
                           TEST
                    </div>
                  </td>
             </tr>
   </tbody>
```

Comment: I don't know anything about bootstrap but just fake a "click" on page load?

Comment: `onload = "document.getElementById("myRow").click()"`

Comment: trigger click event on load

Comment: try aria-expanded="true", according to http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: You should really switch to UI Bootstrap (or the latest version of AngularStrap).  These are substitutes for the Bootstrap jQuery plugins that are written as pure AngularJS directives.  Then you can get rid of all of that jQuery and just initialize the rows you want expanded on your model.  https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/top